# integer programming with indicators

Tags: linear-programming, integer-programming, linearization

I have the following question, and I need to write it as an integer programming problem:

A manager of a company wants to give presents to his 1000 employers. He can buy the presents from two different suppliers:

1. Every present costs 110\$. For any present above 500, the manager would have to pay 5\$ extra for insurance (for example, for 502 presents, there will be 10\$ extra for insurance).
2. Every present costs 120$. For any present above 300, there is a discount of 30% (each present above 300 costs 84\$).

I need to find how many presents he should buy from each supplier, in order to spend the minimal amount of money.

I defined:

$x_1, x_2$ - The number of presents to buy from each supplier.

$z_1$ - Indicator which represents whether or not $x_1 \ge501$

$z_2$ - Indicator which represents whether or not $x_2 \ge301$

I know how to represents the indicators using linear functions, but I don't know how to find a linear objective function.

My best suggestion is:

$$ 110x_1+5z_1(x_1-500)+120x_2-36z_2(x_2-300) $$

However, this is not a linear function, because I multiply the decision variables.

How can I turn it into a linear function?

Answer (score 1):

Introduce nonnegative integer decision variables $y_1$ and $y_2$ to represent "extra" presents.  The problem is to minimize
$$110x_1+5y_1+120x_2-36y_2$$
subject to
\begin{align}
x_1 &\le 500 + y_1 \tag1 \\
y_2 &\le (1000-300) z_2 \tag2 \\
x_2 &\ge 300 z_2 \tag3
\end{align}
Constraint $(1)$ and the objective enforce $y_1 = \max\{x_1-500, 0\}$.  You don't need $z_1$.
Constraint $(2)$ enforces $y_2 > 0 \implies z_2 = 1$.
Constraint $(3)$ enforces $z_2 = 1 \implies x_2 \ge 300$.